# Python Skip Certain Lines in Large Text File

Tags: python

I have a very large text file that I'm reading. When I run my code, I get a 'list index out of range' error. I noticed that certain lines need to be ignored in my data. Each set of 9 lines should look like the 1st example below. Some sets have a random line (see second set). How do I ignore or delete certain lines so that my count isn't thrown off? I need all the data to be in sets of 9 lines. Could I perhaps require line 1 to begin with product, lines 2-8 being with review, and line 9 be blank?

```
product/productId: B001E4KFG0
review/userId: A3SGXH7AUHU8GW
review/profileName: delmartian
review/helpfulness: 1/1
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1303862400
review/summary: Good Quality Dog Food
review/text: I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have
found them all to be of good quality. The product looks more like a stew than a
processed meat and it smells better. My Labrador is finicky and she appreciates this
product better than most.

product/productId: B001E4KFG0
review/userId: A3SGXH7AUHU8GW
review/profileName: delmartian
review/helpfulness: 1/1
error error error
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1303862400
review/summary: Good Quality Dog Food
review/text: I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have
found them all to be of good quality. The product looks more like a stew than a
processed meat and it smells better. My Labrador is finicky and she appreciates this
product better than most.
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import collections

%time
with open('foods.txt',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as food_file:

    dict_list = []
    column_names = ('Product ID', 'Number of people who voted this review helpful', 'Total number of people who rated this review', 'Rating of product', 'Text of the review')

    line_num = 1
    while line_num <20000000:  
        #Read Lines
        line1 = food_file.readline()
        line2 = food_file.readline()
        line3 = food_file.readline()
        line4 = food_file.readline()
        line5 = food_file.readline()
        line6 = food_file.readline()
        line7 = food_file.readline()
        line8 = food_file.readline()
        line9 = food_file.readline()

        #Break out of the loop if we hit the end of the file
        if not line1:
            break

        #This code when in use tells me the last successful line. I then searched the text file to make corrections.
        #Manual process - not desirable
        #if len(line9) > 1:
            #print(line9)
            #break

        #Split Lines for Dataframe
        prod = line1.split(':')[1].strip()
        helpful = line4.split(':')[1].strip()
        helpful = helpful.split('/')[0] #More efficient approach?
        review_total = "/".join(line4.split("/",2)[2:]).strip()
        rating = line5.split(':')[1].strip()
        review_text = line8.split(':')[1].strip()    

        dict_list.append(collections.OrderedDict(zip(column_names, [prod, helpful, review_total, rating, review_text])))

        line_num += 9

amazon_df = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
amazon_df
```

Comment: You should include your code

Comment: If there is a blank line between each group you can start by splitting your text by `text.split("\n\n")`. That way instead of processing your whole file you will process a list of chunks where each chunk can be processed by a similar method. Also often times there will be a blank line at the end of the file that can throw off parsing. Beware of that.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to use a list of dictionary to get each group of nine lines. You can then use the beginning of the line as a dictionary key, eg `my_dict["review/time"]= #the line of text you want`